# Idiorm - Fatal error: Class 'Controller\ORM' not found

Tags: php, orm, idiorm

I am using [Idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm) and looking to update a row with the column name 'path' in

```
$image = ORM::for_table('shop_product_images')->find_one($productId);
$image->path = '/img/shop/products/'.$name;
$image->save();
```

However when this is ran, the response error is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Controller\ORM' not found
```

Which points to the top line of the query.

I should note that a create query works correctly:

```
$image = \ORM::for_table('shop_product_images')->create();
$image->productId = $productId;
$image->path = '/img/shop/products/'.$name;
$image->save();
```

Comment: Have you included the Class ORM before using its function ?

Comment: You already answered the question yourself. In the working example at the bottom you use `\ORM`, so the global namespace for a class `ORM`, which apparently exists. In the failing example you use a class `ORM` in the _current_ namespace (because of the missing leading \\), which results in the engine looking just where you told it to look for the class, in the current namespace `Controller`, where it does _not_ exist.

Comment: Ah silly me! I think I need some rest! Thank you for spotting it